# Android toast equivalent in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm new to JavaFX and I wonder if there is some equivalent to [Android Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)?
I have seen the class `Notification`, but it doesn't look like it can be displayed only in the  application.  I also found I could user a `Timer` and make shading of a `Label`, but if there's some class to use, I'd be better!

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the third party [ControlsFX Notifications or Notification Pane](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#notifications).

"The NotificationPane control allows you to notify your users of something without requiring their immediate input (which you can do with the ControlsFX dialogs API). The NotificationPane will animate in and out of view"

[image: toast1]

Notifications "will show a notification message to users in one of nine locations on the screen ... After a set duration, the notification will fade out."

[image: toast2]

Answer (score 48):

I know it has been a long time since you post this, but I have just made an android-like toast message for javafx, so I post it here in case that someone need this kind of code.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public final class Toast
{
    public static void makeText(Stage ownerStage, String toastMsg, int toastDelay, int fadeInDelay, int fadeOutDelay)
    {
        Stage toastStage=new Stage();
        toastStage.initOwner(ownerStage);
        toastStage.setResizable(false);
        toastStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        Text text = new Text(toastMsg);
        text.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 40));
        text.setFill(Color.RED);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(text);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 20; -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); -fx-padding: 50px;");
        root.setOpacity(0);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        toastStage.setScene(scene);
        toastStage.show();

        Timeline fadeInTimeline = new Timeline();
        KeyFrame fadeInKey1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(fadeInDelay), new KeyValue (toastStage.getScene().getRoot().opacityProperty(), 1)); 
        fadeInTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(fadeInKey1);   
        fadeInTimeline.setOnFinished((ae) -> 
        {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(toastDelay);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                   Timeline fadeOutTimeline = new Timeline();
                    KeyFrame fadeOutKey1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(fadeOutDelay), new KeyValue (toastStage.getScene().getRoot().opacityProperty(), 0)); 
                    fadeOutTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(fadeOutKey1);   
                    fadeOutTimeline.setOnFinished((aeb) -> toastStage.close()); 
                    fadeOutTimeline.play();
            }).start();
        }); 
        fadeInTimeline.play();
    }
}
```

You can make a toast message from any class with this code:

```
String toastMsg = "some text...";
int toastMsgTime = 3500; //3.5 seconds
int fadeInTime = 500; //0.5 seconds
int fadeOutTime= 500; //0.5 seconds
Toast.makeText(primarystage, toastMsg, toastMsgTime, fadeInTime, fadeOutTime);
```

Comment: This works as advertised, so +1 from me. But I didn't need it in the end ;)

Comment: what is "primaryStage"?

Comment: primaryStage is the stage where the toast message will be attached. If you have only one stage then primaryStage is the parameter of the method start of your application. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html

Comment: Rather than creating a thread and running JavaFX code off of the JavaFX application  (which is highly not recommended), a [PauseTransition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792812/android-toast-equivalent-in-javafx/26807559#26807559) may be used and the three transitions (fade in, pause, fade out) can be grouped together using a [SequentialTransition](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html).

Comment: not know why, not worked for me, even not showing any error

Answer (score 0):

To create own toast by using own fxml layout:

```
package controllers;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;


public class ToastController {

    public static final int TOAST_SUCCESS = 11;
    public static final int TOAST_WARN = 12;
    public static final int TOAST_ERROR = 13;

    @FXML
    private HBox containerToast;

    @FXML
    private Label textToast;

    private void setToast(int toastType, String content){
        textToast.setText(content);
        switch (toastType){
            case TOAST_SUCCESS:
                containerToast.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #9FFF96");
                break;
            case TOAST_WARN:
                containerToast.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFCF82");
                break;
            case TOAST_ERROR:
                containerToast.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FF777C");
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void showToast(int toastTyoe, Control control, String text){
        Stage dialog = new Stage();
        dialog.initOwner(control.getScene().getWindow());
        dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        double dialogX = dialog.getOwner().getX();
        double dialogY = dialog.getOwner().getY();
        double dialogW = dialog.getOwner().getWidth();
        double dialogH = dialog.getOwner().getHeight();

        double posX = dialogX + dialogW/2;
        double posY = dialogY + dialogH/6 *5;
        dialog.setX(posX);
        dialog.setY(posY);

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(ToastController.class.getResource("/fxml/toastPopup.fxml"));
            loader.load();
            ToastController ce = loader.getController();
            ce.setToast(toastTyoe,text);
            dialog.setScene(new Scene(loader.getRoot()));
            dialog.show();
            new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                    Duration.millis(1500),
                    ae -> {
                        dialog.close();
                    })).play();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<HBox fx:id="containerToast" alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.ToastController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="textToast" text="TEST" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
   </padding>
</HBox>
```

to run toast just use: 
One of 3 types of toast:
ToastController.TOAST_ERROR
ToastController.TOAST_SUCCESS
ToastController.TOAST_WARN

```
@FXML
private Label idOfAnyControl;

showToast(ToastController.TOAST_WARN,idOfAnyControl,"ERROR TEXT")
```

if you want you can extract 2 additional options by dependency injection (time and position of toast)

Answer (score 0):

@alcoolis equivalent in kotlin

```
Toast.makeText(primaryStage, "No data selected!")


class Toast {

companion object {
    fun makeText(stage: Stage, message: String, displayTime: Int = 3000, fadeInDelay: Int = 500, fadeOutDelay: Int = 500, size: Double = 15.0, opacity: Double = 5.0) {
        val toastStage = Stage()
        toastStage.initOwner(stage)
        toastStage.isResizable = false
        toastStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)

        val text = Text(message)
        text.font = Font.font("Verdana", size)
        text.fill = Color.RED

        val root = StackPane(text)
        root.style = "-fx-background-radius: 20; -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); -fx-padding: 50px;"
        root.opacity = opacity

        val scene = Scene(root)
        scene.fill = Color.TRANSPARENT
        toastStage.scene = scene
        toastStage.show()

        val fadeInTimeline = Timeline()
        val fadeInKey1 =
            KeyFrame(Duration.millis(fadeInDelay.toDouble()), KeyValue(toastStage.scene.root.opacityProperty(), 1))
        fadeInTimeline.keyFrames.add(fadeInKey1)
        fadeInTimeline.setOnFinished {
            Thread {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(displayTime.toLong())
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                val fadeOutTimeline = Timeline()
                val fadeOutKey1 =
                    KeyFrame(
                        Duration.millis(fadeOutDelay.toDouble()),
                        KeyValue(toastStage.scene.root.opacityProperty(), 0)
                    )
                fadeOutTimeline.keyFrames.add(fadeOutKey1)
                fadeOutTimeline.setOnFinished { toastStage.close() }
                fadeOutTimeline.play()
            }.start()
        }
        fadeInTimeline.play()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

@acoolis version with up-to-date JavaFX transitions as suggested by @jewelsea.

```
public final class ToastHelper {
    public static void makeText(Stage ownerStage, String toastMsg, int toastDelay, int fadeInDelay, int fadeOutDelay) {
        final Stage toastStage = new Stage();
        toastStage.initOwner(ownerStage);
        toastStage.setResizable(false);
        toastStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        final Text text = new Text(toastMsg);
    
        final StackPane root = new StackPane(text);
        root.getStyleClass().add("my-dialog-toast");

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        toastStage.setScene(scene);
        toastStage.show();

        // make effect: fade-in, pause, then fade-out effect varying the opacity of the whole window
        final javafx.animation.FadeTransition inTransition = new FadeTransition(new Duration(fadeInDelay),
            toastStage.getScene().getRoot());
        inTransition.setFromValue(0.0);
        inTransition.setToValue(1);

        final javafx.animation.FadeTransition outTransition = new FadeTransition(new Duration(fadeOutDelay),
            toastStage.getScene().getRoot());
        outTransition.setFromValue(1.0);
        outTransition.setToValue(0);

        final javafx.animation.PauseTransition pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(new Duration(toastDelay));

        final javafx.animation.SequentialTransition mainTransition = new SequentialTransition(
            inTransition, pauseTransition, outTransition);
        mainTransition.setOnFinished(ae -> toastStage.close());
        mainTransition.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the style sheet "style.css"?