# JavaFX How to create a flash message at run time

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am new to JavaFX and I want to create a function which someone can call to have a piece of text appear for a few seconds then disappear. I am not sure how it would work. Would I need to add a new scene or can I add it to the same scene and reset the stage?

Comment: Give [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/) Notifications a look, that might solve your problem.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in JavaFX as this is a group project and I am not sure if I am allowed to use ControlFX?

Comment: Then I'd suggest showing a [Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) and invoking [close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#close--) after X seconds

Comment: Depends on how you want to display the message (new window/ overlay over the current scene/...). Just show it immediately and use the `onFinished` handler of a `PauseTransition` to hide it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android toast equivalent in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792812/android-toast-equivalent-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your question is duplicated!

Look at this Post: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38373408/8087490). Works quite well for me.

It's like a Toast in Android: [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts)

In the first link are also other examples that all work fine

Comment: I was wondering how to do this without using the controlFX library since I wasn't sure if I was allowed to use it. I am just using an alert thanks for the link tho! I will definitely use that in the future. :P