# Show "Flash" messages with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

My goal is to have a function to show flash messages (small messages on the top, like notifications), which disappear after a couple of seconds. I currently achieve this with a `stage` and a `javafx.concurrent.Task`:

```java
    public static void showFlashMessage(String message) {

        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        ...

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

        Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                return null;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            window.close();
        });
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
```

But when the user clicks on the main stage, the flash message disappears. Calling `window.toFront()` only moves the window to the front ones.
I want this message to look the same everywhere, like the build in `Alert` but furthermore I can't set `window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL)`, because this wouldn't allow interaction with the main stage.
Is there a good way to achieve this? I pretty much can't show these messages in the existing layouts, they have very different structures and it wouldn't look the same everywhere. And a second benefit of a stage is, that it survives layout changes in the background.

Comment: `window.setAlwaysOnTop(true)`?

Comment: @James_D Thanks, this does work. I always searched for "front" and not top, sorry ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, setting `Stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true)` will work.

While `Task` works, for purely screen animations you should probably stick with the JavaFX Animation tools.  Timeline works well here, and also allows you to make the flash message a little slicker by having a slight fade-in and fade out on the layout.  Like this:

```
   private void showFlashMessage(String message) {
        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        VBox layout = new VBox(10, new Text(message));
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(3));
        layout.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.PINK, new CornerRadii(3), Insets.EMPTY)));
        window.setScene(new Scene(layout, Color.TRANSPARENT));
        window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, evt -> window.show(), new KeyValue(layout.opacityProperty(), 0)),
                                         new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new KeyValue(layout.opacityProperty(), 1.0)),
                                         new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2600), new KeyValue(layout.opacityProperty(), 1.0)),
                                         new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), new KeyValue(layout.opacityProperty(), 0.2)));
        timeline.setOnFinished(evt -> window.close());
        timeline.play();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it work as you want it you can specify the owner Window for the stage. This has to happen before the stage is visible.

```
window.initOwner(ownerStage);
```

Otherwise you could also think about setting the Window to always on Top.

```
window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

You might also want to take a look into this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38373408/14464722

Which shows how to make a Android Style Toast.